# When did the incarnate Jesus begin to exist?

Tags: christology, incarnation

I assume before Gabriel spoke to Mary, the incarnate Jesus did not exist.  Therefore, at some point in time the incarnation began to exist.  When did this happen?

0. Sometime before Mary assented?
1. As soon as Mary assented?
2. At conception?
3. Sometime after conception and before birth?
4. Sometime after birth?

Comment: The incarnation is when the Son of God took on a complete human nature, both body and soul. So the question then is when does a human get a soul? Most Christians would say from the moment of conception, but there might be some who say some other point during embryonic development.